# Сокращение точности decimal в C#

Tags: c#

Допустим у меня число делится на другое число, как мне сделать так, чтобы в любом случае было N цифр после запятой в типе decimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Структура `Decimal` имеет для этого статические методы: [Decimal.Round](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=netcore-3.1)